# SQL Add next year data to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, addition

I want to make a forecast based on weeks.
I have the table like this.

```
personName, year, week1, ..., week52.
```

And would like to add the next year to columns based on how much week i need.
Some kind of select in select.

The final select should look like this:

```
select personName, week1,week2,..., (nextyear)week1,(nextyear)week2,.. from x
```

Any ideas how can I move the next year up to columns?

Comment: the same database, same table

Comment: @dare2k - Joe wanted to know which *brand* of database you are using: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc. It helps if you tag your question with this info as the SQL dialect available to solve your problem can be different in each.

Comment: oh sorry then :)
Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make rows for your data instead of columns - for the exact reason that you are asking about.

Something like this structure:

```
personName Year Week
```

Then you can do a query like:

```
select week from table1 where year=$year-1 and week=$week
```

or pure SQL like this:

```
select
    a.personName
    a.week,
    a.year
from
    table1 a
        join table1 b
            on a.personName=b.personName
            and a.week=b.week
            and a.year=b.year-1
```

However, this similar approach *could* be used with your table something like this:

```
select
    a.personName
    a.week1,
    a.week2,
    a.week3,
    b.week1,
    b.week2,
    b.week3,
    a.year
from
    table1 a
        join table1 b
            on a.personName=b.personName
            and a.year=b.year-1
```